# avro 1.8.1 BigInteger conversion

Tags: java, spring, avro

We have one of fields in avro which is of BigInteger type. However avro does not support BigInteger. Is it possible to handle BigInteger in avro?
We are using avro version 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

can you use some other type in  Avro  (double or long). It same - right ?